# JDBC PreparedStatement always returns 1 as auto generated key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code trying to insert a record in the database:

```
try {
 Connection conn = getConnection();

 String sql = 
   "INSERT INTO myTable(userId,content,timestamp) VALUES(?,?,NOW())";
 PreparedStatement st = 
    conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

 st.setLong(1, userId);
 st.setString(2, content);
 id = st.executeUpdate(); //this is the problem line            
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

The problem is, though the record is inserted correctly, I want `id` to contain the primary key + auto_increment id of the record that was just inserted. However, for some reason, it always returns '1' as the id, possibly because the value of `userId` is 1 during the inserts.

My table is InnoDB. At first `userId` was a foreign key to another table, owever I've since deleted the foreign key and even the index on the userId column, but I'm still getting 1 as the return value.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **PreparedStatment.executeUpdate()**
>
> **Returns:**
>   either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

You need to use `execute()` instead and get the `ResultSet` with `getGeneratedKeys()`; it's going to contain the data you want.

**Edit to add:** I read your question as there is an auto-increment field in the table that is *not* `userId`

Comment: Then what's the point of `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` if I have to fetch it by getting the result set?

Comment: Huh? If you don't specify that ... you don't get them back at all. It's not making *another* query - the problem is you're discarding the returned data because you're using `executeUpdate()`

Comment: I switched to `st.executeQuery();` and now I get: `DB Exception occured:java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

Comment: Ah sorry, doing this partially from memory forgot you have to use `execute()` after reading the docs :) - editing

Comment: Thanks for the help. Doing `ResultSet rs =getGeneratedKeys()` and then `rs.next(); id = rs.getLong(1)` worked for me.

Comment: Cool - sorry about not knowing it precisely I should have refreshed first, it's been a while. Glad I could help and I'm going to edit to match your comment.

Comment: You can actually use `executeUpdate()` here (at least if the driver implementation is compliant with the JDBC spec), but you still need to use `getGeneratedKeys()`

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844924/642706) by Brian Roach is correct. I'm adding some thoughts and an example with full code.

## `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` Does *Not* Mean “return generated keys”

The original poster seems to be confused, understandably, by the phrasing of the flag [`Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS). Contrary to intuition, passing this flag does *not* change the behavior of the [`PreparedStatement::executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) method. That method always returns an `int`, the number of rows affected by the SQL executed. The "executeUpdate" method never returns the generated keys.

```
int countRowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();  // Always return number of rows affected, *not* the generated keys.
```

### Ask, and Ye Shall Receive

If you want the generated keys, you must do *two* steps:

1. Pass the flag, *and*
2. Ask for a `ResultSet` made up of rows containing only the generated key values.

This arrangement allows you to add the behavior of getting back generated keys while keeping the other desirable behavior, getting a count of the number of rows affected.

## Example Code

Here is a nearly real-world example taken from a Java 8 app that scrapes data from a data feed. I think in this context a full-blown example may be more useful than a minimal one.

Minor details… This code may not be perfect, syntactically or otherwise, as I copy-pasted-modified real source code. I am using the [UUID data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) rather than integers as the [surrogate](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjABahUKEwjEz478yuHGAhVNE5IKHb2vCSo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSurrogate_key&ei=FaeoVYTxLc2myAS936bQAg&usg=AFQjCNGl7ZK6MPC2regSldkG8pmNVNKiOw&sig2=3Cx1wKOyg809BXg_wxt16A&bvm=bv.98197061,d.aWw) primary key of my table. The classes `CharHelper` and `DBHelper` are my own, the details of which are not important here. The `x` and `y` variables are replacements of my own app's meaningful data. My logging calls are made to the [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) framework. The [UUID](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwiumfKZxuHGAhWIXZIKHS3_BY4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUniversally_unique_identifier&ei=FqKoVa62AYi7yQSt_pfwCA&v6u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com%2Fgen_204%3Fip%3D184.78.240.187%26ts%3D1437114902375870%26auth%3Dbg5jnuwzldniuzrs6327stz4ncwdz2kq%26rndm%3D0.5389944924972951&v6s=2&v6t=983&usg=AFQjCNHgfHdxVqsJezox04UolXSo17nqzw&sig2=PPImXTLwGvcbqyl82CdV7A&bvm=bv.98197061,d.aWw) [hex](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjABahUKEwi5ksahxuHGAhUWD5IKHQTFDl4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHexadecimal&ei=JqKoVbnnBJaeyASEirvwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEupvQmHCJhPcDMp3b-rL4fMsAPFw&sig2=uBXr7fBIbZU8Y8raeszCGQ&bvm=bv.98197061,d.aWw) strings are a convenient way to link reports in the logs back to the original source code. The database is [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), but this kind of code should work on any database supporting the reporting of generating keys.

```java
public UUID dbWrite (  String x , String y , DateTime whenRetrievedArg ) {
    if ( whenRetrievedArg == null ) {
        logger.error( "Passed null for whenRetrievedArg. Message # 2112ed1a-4612-4d5d-8cc5-bf27087a350d." );
        return null;
    }

    Boolean rowInsertComplete = Boolean.FALSE; // Might be used for debugging or logging or some logic in other copy-pasted methods.

    String method = "Method 'dbWrite'";
    String message = "Insert row for some_table_ in " + method + ". Message # edbea872-d3ed-489c-94e8-106a8e3b58f7.";
    this.logger.trace( message );

    String tableName = "some_table_";

    java.sql.Timestamp tsWhenRetrieved = new java.sql.Timestamp( whenRetrievedArg.getMillis() );  // Convert Joda-Time DatTime object to a java.sql.Timestamp object.

    UUID uuidNew = null;

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder( AbstractPersister.INITIAL_CAPACITY_OF_SQL_STRING ); // private final static Integer INITIAL_CAPACITY_OF_SQL_STRING = 1024;
    sql.append( "INSERT INTO " ).append( tableName ).append( CharHelper.CHAR.PAREN_OPEN_SPACED ).append( " x_ , y_ " ).append( CharHelper.CHAR.PAREN_CLOSED ).append( DBHelper.SQL_NEWLINE );
    sql.append( "VALUES ( ? , ? , ?  ) " ).append( DBHelper.SQL_NEWLINE );
    sql.append( ";" );

    try ( Connection conn = DBHelper.instance().dataSource().getConnection() ;
```

Here we do **Step # 1**, pass the `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` flag.

```java
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql.toString() , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ); ) {
```

We continue to prepare and execute the statement. Note that `int countRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();` returns the count of affected rows, not the generated keys.

```java
        pstmt.setString( 1 , x ); 
        pstmt.setString( 2 , y ); 
        pstmt.setTimestamp( 3 , tsWhenRetrieved );  
        // Execute
        int countRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();  // Always returns an int, a count of affected rows. Does *not* return the generated keys.
        if ( countRows == 0 ) {  // Bad.
            this.logger.error( "Insert into database for new " + tableName + " failed to affect any rows. Message # 67e8de7e-67a5-42a6-a4fc-06929211e6e3." );
        } else if ( countRows == 1 ) {  // Good.
            rowInsertComplete = Boolean.TRUE;
        } else if ( countRows > 1 ) {  // Bad.
            rowInsertComplete = Boolean.TRUE;
            this.logger.error( "Insert into database for new " + tableName + " failed, affecting more than one row. Should not be possible. Message # a366e215-6cf2-4e5c-8443-0b5d537cbd68." );
        } else { // Impossible.
            this.logger.error( "Should never reach this Case-Else with countRows value " + countRows + " Message # 48af80d4-6f50-4c52-8ea8-98856873f3bb." );
        }
```

Here we do **Step # 2**, ask for a ResultSet of the generated keys. In the case of this example, we inserted a single row and expect back a single generated key.

```java
        if ( rowInsertComplete ) {
            // Return new row’s primary key value.
            ResultSet genKeys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if ( genKeys.next() ) {
                uuidNew = ( UUID ) genKeys.getObject( 1 );  // ResultSet should have exactly one column, the primary key of INSERT table.
            } else {
                logger.error( "Failed to get a generated key returned from database INSERT. Message # 6426843e-30b6-4237-b110-ec93faf7537d." );
            }
        }
```

The rest is error-handling and clean-up. Do note that **we return the UUID**, the generated primary key of the inserted record, at the bottom of this code.

```java
    } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
        // We expect to have occasional violations of unique constraint on this table in this data-scraping app.
        String sqlState = ex.getSQLState();
        if ( sqlState.equals( DBHelper.SQL_STATE.POSTGRES.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION ) ) {  // SqlState code '23505' = 'unique_violation'.
            this.logger.trace( "Found existing row when inserting a '" + tableName + "' row for y: " + y + ". Expected to happen on most attempts. Message # 0131e8aa-0bf6-4d19-b1b3-2ed9d333df27." );
            return null; // Bail out.
        } else { // Else any other exception, throw it.
            this.logger.error( "SQLException during: " + method + " for table: " + tableName + ", for y: " + y + ". Message # 67908d00-2a5f-4e4e-815c-5e5a480d614b.\n" + ex );
            return null; // Bail out.
        }
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        this.logger.error( "Exception during: " + method + " for table: " + tableName + ", for y: " + y + ". Message # eecc25d8-de38-458a-bb46-bd6f33117969.\n" + ex );
        return null;  // Bail out.
    }

    if ( uuidNew == null ) {
        logger.error( "Returning a null uuidNew var. SQL: {} \nMessage # 92e2374b-8095-4557-a4ed-291652c210ae." , sql );
    }
    return uuidNew;
}
```

Comment: In your **Step #2**, under what circumstances would you get to the `else`, where a row was inserted (because `countRows == 1`), but the `getGeneratedKeys()` failed?  I would have thought this a frivolous `if / else` (like the last `else` marked "Impossible"), except that I'm at that point and trying to figure out how I got there.

Comment: @Menachem Strictly speaking, that `if()` check does seem to be impossible. But I've learned to expect the impossible. My multiple lines in the earlier `if ( countRows…` do not stop flow-of-control, so we could end up proceeding to ask for generated keys for zero inserted rows. Even if the `countRows` checks stopped flow-of-control, those checks might get screwed up with typos like `<` instead of `>`. Plus, something could go haywire with the generated keys, so I'm checking. I practice defensive coding, doing extra checks for many of my assumptions along the way even if impossible in theory.

Comment: Thanks.  My point was: the (seemingly) impossible situation of `countRows ==1` and yet `genKeys.next()` returning false - that's where I am now, and I'm trying to figure out why.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447602/getgeneratedkeys-returns-an-empty-resultset)

Comment: @Menachem Ahh, you are asking if I knew of an actual problem/issue/situation that could cause `getGeneratedKeys` to occasionally fail and produce an empty ResultSet. I’ve no idea. I did indeed think of that command failing, and therefore added my defensive coding to check. But that was due to paranoid worry, not knowledge of any real problem. I've not yet had any such problem occur. The `Statement` class doc does mention that method specifically throwing a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. But that would not explain your intermittent fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
String SQLQuery=" ";

String generatedKeys[]= {"column_name"};//'column_name' auto-increment column

prepSt = Connection.prepareStatement(SQLQuery,generatedKeys);

prepSt.setInt(1, 1234); 

.....

.....

....


prepSt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = prepSt.getGeneratedKeys; // used same PreparedStatement object as used   for Insert .


if(rs.next()) {


int id=rs.getLong("column_name");


System.out.println(id);


}
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a catch without a try here, so it's a bit confusing. Please could you explain your answer in words as well as code?

Comment: @Parb Thanks for posting some example code. But please add some discussion. StackOverflow is meant to be educational and enlightening, not simply a snippet collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set `userId` has auto-increment in your database, you shouldn't try and add it yourself. You should insert `NULL`, and it will auto-increment for you! (The clue is in the name!)

Also, you are not updating your table, you are inserting into it. So you don't executeUpdate(). Try...

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTable(userId,content,timestamp) VALUES(NULL,?,NOW())");
pst.setString(1, content);
pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: no, userId isn't the auto_increment, a seperate field `id` is the auto_increment

Comment: Can you describe your table so we know what exactly your wanting to add to what?

Answer (score 1):

What you get is the notification of 'Rows insetrted' (for INSERT statement). We use this method to know whether our DML query is succesful or not. The following is the way to get the Auto generated ID using [prepareStatement(yourSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)]. Pls note that this method only return you a RowID ref. To get the actual val, pls refer to Method 2.

(Method 1)

```
Try{
String yourSQL="insert into Table1(Id,Col2,Col3) values(SEQ.nextval,?,?)";
myPrepStatement = <Connection>.prepareStatement(yourSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
myPrepStatement.setInt(1, 123); 
myPrepStatement.setInt(2, 123); 

myPrepStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = getGeneratedKeys;
if(rs.next()) {
  java.sql.RowId rid=rs.getRowId(1); 
  //what you get is only a RowId ref, try make use of it anyway U could think of
  System.out.println(rid);
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

(Method 2)

```
Try{
String yourSQL="insert into Table1(Id,Col2,Col3) values(SEQ.nextval,?,?)";
//IMPORTANT: here's where other threads don tell U, you need to list ALL cols 
//mentioned in your query in the array
myPrepStatement = <Connection>.prepareStatement(yourSQL, new String[]{"Id","Col2","Col3"});
myPrepStatement.setInt(1, 123); 
myPrepStatement.setInt(2, 123); 
myPrepStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = getGeneratedKeys;
if(rs.next()) {
//In this exp, the autoKey val is in 1st col
  int id=rs.getLong(1);
  //now this's a real value of col Id
  System.out.println(id);
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

Basically, try not used Method1 if you just want the value of SEQ.Nextval, b'cse it just return the RowID ref that you may cracked your head finding way to make use of it, which also don fit all data type you tried casting it to! This may works fine (return actual val) in MySQL, DB2 but not in Oracle.

IMPORTANT: 
Turn off your SQL Developer, Toad or any client which use the same login session to do INSERT when you're debugging. It MAY not affect you every time (debugging call) ... until you find your apps freeze without exception for some time. Yes ... halt without exception!