# JDBC query RETURNING value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem trying to figure out how to get the id of the last inserted row using PostgreSQL and JDBC.

```
    CREATE TABLE vet_care (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        deworming int,
        castration int
    );
```

My query is

```
String insertVetCare = "INSERT INTO vet_care(castration,deworming) VALUES("+castrated+","+dewormed+") RETURNING id";
```

I want the id value (which is serial) for later use. I tried to execute the query like so:

```
int id = statement.executeUpdate(insertVetCare);
```

But this says after compilation, that "A result was returned when none was expected." and it does not insert the other values into table.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please don't do string concatenation like this. It's a bad habit, even if `castrated` and `dewormed` are boolean or integer and thus safe in this case. SQL injection ahoy.

Answer (score 3):

If "id" means "generated identity key", then you've got it wrong.

The `executeUpdate()` method returns the number of affected rows, according to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

You want it to return auto generated keys, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376218/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-autoincrement-id-from-a-prepared-statement).

More advice: Use `PreparedStatement` and bind values.  Building up a SQL query that way is asking for a SQL injection attack.

```
// Why make the gc work?  This query never changes.
private static final String INSERT_VET_CARE = "INSERT INTO vet_care(castration,deworming) VALUES(?, ?)";


PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_VET_CARE,  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.setInt(1, castration);
ps.setInt(2, deworming);
```