# java.lang.NullPointerException when using returning().fetchOne()

Tags: jooq

Note: This code used to work as I used PostgreSQL. After switching to MySQL these functions stopped working for some reason.

---

I double checked: `languageId` and `shopId` are valid IDs and there is a valid entry of `supported_language` resembling the inserted record after `fetchOne()` but it returns `null`.

```java
private Long addSupportedLanguage(Long languageId, Long shopId) {

    Long value = this.ctx.insertInto(SHOP_LANGUAGE)
        .set(SHOP_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE_ID, languageId)
        .set(SHOP_LANGUAGE.SHOP_ID, shopId)
        .returning()
        .fetchOne() // After this line I see the record in my db but it returns null
        .getValue(SHOP_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE_ID);

    return value;
}
```

I also tried using

```java
.returning(RESTAURANT_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE_ID)
```

but the result is the same.

I am observing something similar when calling `returnin()` after a `delete()` statement:

```java
public void deleteEmailVerificationToken(String token) {

    ShopAdminVerificationTokenRecord shopAdminVerificationTokenRecord = this
            .ctx.delete(SHOP_ADMIN_VERIFICATION_TOKEN)
            .where(SHOP_ADMIN_VERIFICATION_TOKEN.VERIFICATION_TOKEN.eq(token))
            .returning()
            .fetchOne()
            .into(SHOP_ADMIN_VERIFICATION_TOKEN);

    if(shopAdminVerificationTokenRecord != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("Deleted verification token for " + shopAdminVerificationTokenRecord.getUserEmail());
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("The given token was not found.");
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. The new record gets correctly inserted but still I cannot fetch that record immediately after insertion.

---

I created `SHOP_LANGUAGE` and all other objects using the jOOQ code generator. This is the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement that I used to create the table for a MySQL database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shop_language (

    shop_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_language__shop
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop(id),

    language_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_language__language
        FOREIGN KEY (language_id)
        REFERENCES language(id),

    PRIMARY KEY (shop_id, language_id)          
);
```

Comment: Did you use the code generator to generate `SHOP_LANGUAGE` and the other objects? What database are you using? Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your `SHOP_LANGUAGE` table?

Comment: @LukasEder I updated my question to provide further information :)

Comment: Hmm, I see... I don't have the jOOQ integration tests ready, so I can't verify this right now, but I think that the MySQL JDBC driver doesn't support returning any values if there is not an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Can you verify this with JDBC directly ([example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1376241/521799)). Anyway, why do you need the returning clause in the first place? Is there a trigger on that column? It appears that you're simply returning the value you've just inserted again...

Comment: @LukasEder I actually wrote that function just to fill my database quick and dirty with some data for testing stuff - you're right, I could also just return `languageId` here. Although I have another scenario where I delete a `token` that I've sent to the user in order to verify his ownership of the provided email address. Here I also used to return the deleted element for example to verify that the token existed when I used PostgreSQL - now with MySQL this is giving me a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, `DELETE .. RETURNING` is not supported for MySQL: http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DeleteReturningStep.html#returning-org.jooq.Field...- (see the `@Support` annotation on that method). You could use the checker framework to validate those support annotations: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/05/09/jsr-308-and-the-checker-framework-add-even-more-typesafety-to-jooq-3-9/

Comment: @LukasEder You never know ... I'm definitely going to check out that checker framework. Looks interesting!

Comment: Just had the same issue with MySQL, @LukasEder your comment should be translated into an answer, they actually give the cause of the issue.

Comment: @L.G.: Indeed, done

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments:

`DELETE .. RETURNING` is not supported for MySQL as documented by the `@Support` annotation on the relevant [`returning()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DeleteReturningStep.html#returning()) methods.