# ResultSet RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS seems not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I made a method for inserting queries into my database.
For lazy multi-threading I use normal Statements. 
Somehow RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS doesn't seem to work... 
I use the latest MySQL driver that supports generated keys according to the documentation.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
public ResultSet insertQuery(String query) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        openIfNotClosed();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        result = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

There is a ResultSet but it is always empty...
I need this for auto increment ids

Thank you in advance

-- EDIT fix missing copy paste part

Comment: What is the complete code ? There is no return here, and you don't try to read the result... EDIT : by complete, I mean the useful part. ;)

Comment: Why don't you use prepareStatement?? See this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376218/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-autoincrement-id-from-a-prepared-statement

Comment: +Shivam Does that make a difference? I used normal statements because pre-compiling a statement doesn't seemed necessary in my context