# How to generate unique integer even if server restarts

Tags: java

Every time receiving specific post request from client, server should produce an unique integer to generate a link(uri: website/question/id/details) and store the integer as index(primary key) in database. I've tried `int idForUri = UniqueInteger.uri.incrementAndGet();` But this doesn't work if server reboots. How can I fix this?

```
class UniqueInteger {
    public static AtomicInteger uri = new AtomicInteger(212043);
}
```

**Add**
table article
------------
id    int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key
title varchar(50) 
content text
uri   varchar(50)

Every specific post request from browser cause server to produce a new uri. User visit that page by the uri, which consists of "website/question/**id**/details"(id is the primary key). But without knowing the new id, the uri is also unknown. For example, 21000 is currently the max id existed in table article. So `insert into article(title, content, uri) values (?, ?, 'website/questions/21001/details')` is needed. But server doesn't know the value of 21001 because of auto-increment(maybe leads to a sql `select` statement before executing `insert`). 

Users by typing specific uri in browser to visit every article page, a HTTP request. Server should know which article to be sent just by the receiving link. So I add id to uri(just like the uri in SO, which is questions/question-id/title).Then by parsing the id filed in uri, server can locate the specific article. 
How to fix the design?

Comment: if the server restarts should the unique int generated again?

Comment: Condition is: Every time receiving specific post request from client, then produce an unique integer. It's better to produce unique integer and its value not too large(less than 1000,000,00).

Comment: I think you are going about this back-to-front - insert into the DB and use the auto-generated key

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Condition is: Every time receiving specific post request from client, server will produce an unique integer .It's better to produce unique integer and its value not too large(less than 1000,000,00).

Comment: @ScaryWombat. With auto-generated key, it leads to add a  select statement in server to produce the link. Because server doesn't know the value before inserting the link into DB(index is auto-generated), so it needs a select.

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1376241/2310289)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think you may not understand my confusion. For example, table article (id auto-increment, uri varchar(50), title varchar(50), content text). Before execute sql statement `insert`, the uri column should know the value of `id` first. Because the uri is filled with (website/id/details)

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: As I read your description the `uri`.column is fully redundant. Why do you need it when the URI can be constructed from the other data?

Comment: @piet.t I've added more details.

Comment: But your addition does not answer: why do you need to store the URI in the database? When a request comes in you know the incoming URI and extract the id. When you need to create a link to an article you read the id from the database and construct the URI in your application.

Comment: @piet.t same thing as I am saying in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your comments, the easiest way would be just to let the DB insert use auto-generated keys as per normal and

change the getUri method to append or insert the id field into it

```
return String.format ("website/question/%d/details", id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the uri is also a column in table article. So you can't execute `insert` before knowing the id.I will add more details in my question to make it clear.

Comment: No I am saying that the url in the DB should not even contain the `id` The **getter** on your EntityBean should do the logic

Comment: I'm still confused about it. When user types a uri in browser, how can server locate specific item in table article without id in uri.

Comment: Do you have an EnityBean for your article record? Maybe you are selecting all (or some) and displaying in a HTML table.  When you read the record you have the id - use it to construct your URL

Answer (score 3):

Use a SEQUENCE or equivalent concept from the database.

Comment: I've added more details in my question.

Comment: The answer still applies: get a new ID value from the database, then insert the record. Also, why do you need to store the URI? Isn't it determined only by knowing the ID.

Comment: Yes, it's detemined only by knowing the ID. Users by typing specific uri in browser to visit every article page, a HTTP request. Server should know which article to be sent just by the receving link. So I add id to uri(Just like the uri in SO, it's questions/question-id/title), then by parsing the id filed in uri, server can locate the specific article.