# How to retrieve all generated keys from multiple row PreparedStatement in Java?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

Assuming the following SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO MATERIAL (ID, CODE, NAME) VALUES
(NULL, 'firstCode', 'firstName'),
(NULL, 'secondCode', 'secondName');
```

Using the follwing code where the `PreparedStatement` instance `ps` represents the SQL statement from above. And the `PreparedStatement` has been obtained with the option `new String[]{"ID"}` in order to specify the column name of the generated keys:

```
try {
    final int affectedRows = ps.executeUpdate();
    assertEquals("failed to insert all entries", "2", String.valueOf(affectedRows));
    final ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    while (generatedKeys.next()) {
      System.out.println(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // some catch block
}
```

The problem is that only the `ID` of the second row will be retrieved. Do you have a suggestion how to retrieve all of the generated keys?

EDIT:

This is the table's definition.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MATERIAL" (
  "ID" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "IDMATERIAL" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  "NAME"       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Really? What is the output of this code?

Comment: @EJP only "2" is put out on System.out ...

Comment: @Muhammad why does it work for a single insert then and why does it return the ID of the row last inserted?

Comment: What is the type of the ID column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376218/1966247 see this answer, I  think this is what you want

Comment: @EJP added the table definition

Comment: @Muhammad I also tried the solution mentioned in the referenced SO question with no success. Anyway, as a work around I now simply add the PreparedStatement to a batch for each instance to be stored into the DB (calling executeBatch()). This works! I will come back to this problem at a later point.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

while(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getLong(1));
}
```

Comment: Try it why? Guesswork isn't an answer. You have to explain.